# $(...).jCarouselLite is not a function

Tags: javascript, jcarousellite

I have this rotator that works in some pages but doesn't work at all in others. On http://www.unitedtruckcenters.com/ it works fine, but if you go to http://www.unitedtruckcenters.com/pre_owned_detail.asp?veh=3328107 you will see that it won't even start. With the Web Developer toolbar, I get the following error message:

Error: TypeError: $(...).jCarouselLite is not a function
Source File: http://www.unitedtruckcenters.com/pre_owned_detail.asp?veh=3328107

Please help, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the extension is loaded before jQuery is loaded, and jQuery overwrites the $ variable.
Put the jquery script tag in the header and the carousel one right below it.

<strike>The problem is that the jQuery extension JCarouselLite is just not loaded on the second page.</strike>

The script (www.unitedtruckcenters.com/jcarousellite.js) is buried somewhere deep in the main page, you should move it to the header and add it to the second page too.

Next time posting on stackoverflow please don't let us do all the work and tell us what you know and show us your code in the question instead of putting some URLs into the post.

Comment: The script *is* loaded, the code
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jcarousellite.js"></script>
Appears in both pages. For some reason, it isn't starting/working.

Anyone willing to help?

Comment: If you have access to the files, try putting an `alert( "test" );` at the start of the file.

If it fires, maybe jquery is loaded after the carousel script.